# Retrieve random key from Hashtable

Tags: java, random, hashtable

Well, i think everything is in the title...

But to make it more clear: i have a Hashtable, where the keys are Strings (more precisely: user names) and the values are a personal class, let's say UserData. So obviously i use this table to retrieve some UserData knowing the user name; but  sometimes i would like to take a random user name.

That's why i need to find a way to select a random key in my Hashtable.

I've tried that:

```java
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomIndex = random.nextInt(myHashtable.size())-1;
            String[] names = null;
            myHashtable.keySet().toArray(names);
            String randomUser = names[randomIndex];
            System.out.println(randomUser);
```

But it doesn't work (i get an error for a bad use of Random, sorry i don't have the details right now)

Comment: Remove the `-1`. And assign a value to `names`.

Comment: Why? if i get it right, Hashtable.size() send the number of entry in my Hashtable; if there's no etry it'll be 0. However, i'm doing this only when there's more than one entry. Let's say there's 2: then, in my String array names, i'll have names[0] and names[1], but not names[2]. That's why i put the -1.

What do you mean by "assign a value to names"? Giving a size to the array? Like that:  String[myHashtable.size()-1] names;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem One: `nextInt(n)` returns a value in the range 0 to n - 1. Adding a `-1` as you currently do results in a value in the range -1 to n - 2 (which is wrong)

Problem Two: `myHashtable.keySet().toArray(names);` returns an array filled with the `keys` (it does not allocate and fill the array).

```
int len = myHashtable.size();
int randomIndex = random.nextInt(len);
String[] names = myHashtable.keySet().toArray(new String[len]); // sizing the
   // array is optional, but you have the length - and if you don't specify it
   // then it will be re-computed.
```

Comment: OK thanks! it seems that i hadn't really understood this function. I'll try it :)

Answer (score 2):

you can just convert `Set` to `List` and use `ThreadLocalRandom` to get random values between range docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-), this approach avoids creating `Random` instance

```
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(myHashtable.keySet());
    System.out.println(l.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, l.size())));
```

> public int nextInt(int origin,
>                      int bound)
>
> Returns a pseudorandom int value between the specified origin (inclusive) and the specified bound (exclusive).